# ¿Por qué "de rodilla en rodilla" quiere decir "de varón en varón"?

Tags: etimología, locuciones

En el Diccionario de la lengua se recoge [**de rodilla en rodilla**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WbiPY7W) como

> 1. loc. adv. **De varón en varón**.

que no parece guardar mucha relación con las acepciones de [**rodilla**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WbiPY7W):

> 1. f. Zona donde se une el muslo con la parte inferior de la pierna.
> 2. f. Región prominente de la rodilla.
> 3. f. En los cuadrúpedos, unión del antebrazo con la caña.
> 4. f. rodete (‖ rosca para llevar peso sobre la cabeza).
> 5. f. Paño basto u ordinario, regularmente de lienzo, que sirve para limpiar, especialmente en la cocina.

¿Por qué tiene **de rodilla en rodilla** ese significado?  ¿Indica  promiscuidad, con relaciones con un varón tras otro?

Answer (score 3):

La verdad es que la definición de la RAE no me deja claro el significado, pero viendo algunos ejemplos en el CORDE queda más claro:

> *Los Bargas es noble gente que -afirman las istorias de España e memorias de linajes que yo tengo-, vienen de rodilla en rodilla derechamente de los godos.*
>
> Juan de Mena, "Memoria de algunos linajes", 1448 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *Súpolo el conde y escribió a la Junta y a Valladolid quejándose mucho que tuviesen tales sospechas de él; que él no venía de vendedores ni de traidores, sino de leales caballeros de los reyes godos de España de rodilla en rodilla.*
>
> Fray Prudencio de Sandoval, "Historia de la vida y hechos del Emperador Carlos V", 1604-1618 (España).

Es decir, la expresión se refiere a los linajes que, desde tiempos inmemoriales, se transmiten entre generaciones mediante los hijos varones. Pero ¿por qué "rodilla"? Lo único que he encontrado al respecto es esto:

> *En cuanto a lo de "nacer de rodilla en rodilla", paréceme que, más bien que en el dominio de la poesía, cae en el de la obstetricia, o sea el arte de partear.*
>
> Ramón de Mesonero Romanos, "Memorias de un setentón", 1880-1881 (España).

"Partear" se usa para los facultativos o comadronas que asisten a la mujer al parto. Hoy día se usa una silla dado que la parturienta suele estar en una cama elevada, pero tal vez antiguamente la postura de las comadronas fuese de rodillas.

Existe otra posibilidad, y es una antigua acepción de "rodilla" que aparece en diccionarios del siglo XVIII que dice "el paño vil, regularmente de lienzo, que sirve para limpiar alguna cosa". Covarrubias afirma además que las mozas lo suelen torcer y poner en la cabeza, "para que no les lastime el peso de lo que llevaren encima". Pero me quedo igual, no sé qué relación puede tener esto con las parturientas (¿tal vez lo usaban para sujetarse el pelo en los partos?) o con los linajes.

O a lo mejor lo de "partear" es una pista falsa, y simplemente se refiere al hecho de que los nobles y reyes debían arrodillarse a la hora de tomar posesión del título (y por tanto transmitir el linaje).